# getting index of series's points when i click on points : highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i want to get an index for the point . when i click on points it should give me index of that point. here i have only sample data but originally i have huge data. right now when i click on points it is giving me x values but i want index instead. please see js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/h2sgqttt/1/

html code

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <div class="row">
            <highchart id="chart1" config="mtv" class="span10"></highchart>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h3><a href="https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng">See Highcharts-ng on github</a></h3>`
```

javascript

```
//See: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.mtv = {

        useHighStocks: true,
        options: {
            xAxis: {
                min: 1435324365737,
                max: 1435324410674,
                type: "datetime",
                plotLines: [],
            }

            ,plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                    click: function(e) {
                        // Log to console
                        alert(this.name + ' clicked\n' +
                              'Index: ' + event.point.x);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
            title: {
                text: 'fssfgdf'
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled: false
            },
            navigator: {
                enabled: false,

            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true
            },
        },
        series: [{

            name: 'gddfdg',
            data: [
                [1435324350703, 1],
                [1435324365737, 1],
                [1435324395659, 1],
                [1435324410674, 1]
            ],
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                radius: 3
            },

        }],

    }

});
```

Comment: Try this: `var index = this.series.xData.indexOf(event.point.x);`.

Comment: it is giving me error can not read property of x ata undefine

Comment: Ah, sorry, you have click for series, not as I expected for the point, see: `var index = this.xData.indexOf(event.point.x);`